# Displaying None and Values with pandas dictionaries Python

Tags: python, pandas, database, numpy, format

There are `None` values indicating there is no value for the `Last Month` row within the dictionary `a` below. How would I be able to modify the pandas style format so that it could print table `a` and still place dollar signs and in front of the set columns?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a =   {'Timeframes': ['Entirety:',
      'Last Month:',
      'Three Months:',
      'Six Months:',
      'Last Year:',
      'Last Two Years:'],
     'Compounding With Lev':  np.array([2398012.89, None, 90.07, 85.29,
            620.39, 30611.48], dtype=object),
     'Compounding With Seperate Levs': np.array([21165662669.71, None, 91.18, 107.54,
            3004.87, 13287947.75], dtype=object),
     'Adjusted Long Compounding Lev': np.array([3.25, None, 1.0, 1.0, 3.5, 4.75], dtype=object),
     'Adjusted Short Compounding Lev': np.array([3.75, None, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0], dtype=object),
     'Non Compounding With Lev': np.array([3626.41, None, 89.95, 95.73,
            1577.75, 1380.80], dtype=object),
     'Non Compounding With Seperate Levs': np.array([5679.53, None, 91.15, 408.40,
            1953.53, 2530.58], dtype=object),
     'Adjusted Long NonCompounding Lev': np.array([4.25, None, 1.0, 1.0, 10.5, 4.25], dtype=object),
     'Adjusted Short NonCompounding Lev': np.array([7.75, None, 1.0, 33.25, 1.0, 7.75], dtype=object)}

display(pd.DataFrame(a).style.format(formatter={'Compounding With Lev': '${:,.2f}',
                       'Compounding With Seperate Levs': '${:,.2f}',
                       'Non Compounding With Lev': '${:,.2f}',
                       'Non Compounding With Seperate Levs': '${:,.2f}'}))
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Any specific reason for using `dtype=object`? Using `dtype=float` automatically converts `None` to `float('nan')` which has no issues with the given code and will output `$nan` in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a =   {'Timeframes': ['Entirety:',
      'Last Month:',
      'Three Months:',
      'Six Months:',
      'Last Year:',
      'Last Two Years:'],
     'Compounding With Lev':  np.array([2398012.89, None, 90.07, 85.29,
            620.39, 30611.48], dtype=float),
     'Compounding With Seperate Levs': np.array([21165662669.71, None, 91.18, 107.54,
            3004.87, 13287947.75], dtype=float),
     'Adjusted Long Compounding Lev': np.array([3.25, None, 1.0, 1.0, 3.5, 4.75], dtype=float),
     'Adjusted Short Compounding Lev': np.array([3.75, None, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0], dtype=float),
     'Non Compounding With Lev': np.array([3626.41, None, 89.95, 95.73,
            1577.75, 1380.80], dtype=float),
     'Non Compounding With Seperate Levs': np.array([5679.53, None, 91.15, 408.40,
            1953.53, 2530.58], dtype=float),
     'Adjusted Long NonCompounding Lev': np.array([4.25, None, 1.0, 1.0, 10.5, 4.25], dtype=float),
     'Adjusted Short NonCompounding Lev': np.array([7.75, None, 1.0, 33.25, 1.0, 7.75], dtype=float)}

display(pd.DataFrame(a).style.format(formatter={'Compounding With Lev': '${:,.2f}',
                       'Compounding With Seperate Levs': '${:,.2f}',
                       'Non Compounding With Lev': '${:,.2f}',
                       'Non Compounding With Seperate Levs': '${:,.2f}'}, na_rep='None'))
```

By changing `dtype=float` we allow `numpy` to place `nan` values in the array. `na_rep` parameter is what the formatter will put when the formatting is not applicable.

To convert dictionary `a` in case your dictionary is read like that from a file and the arrays are already `dtype=object`:

```
for k, v in a.items():
    if isinstance(v, np.ndarray):
        a[k] = v.astype(float)
```